# Validation set with TensorFlow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

From [Train and evaluate with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate):

> The argument validation_split (generating a holdout set from the training data) is not supported when training from Dataset objects, since this features requires the ability to index the samples of the datasets, which is not possible in general with the Dataset API.

Is there a workaround? How can I still use a validation set with TF datasets?

Comment: As posted, the answer is a clear and unambiguous *no*, as obvious from the documentation link. If you want to ask "*how can I still use a **validation set** with TF datasets*", please rephrase accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't use use `validation_split` (as described clearly by documentation), but you can create `validation_data` instead and create `Dataset` "manually".

You can see an example in the same [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#training_evaluation_from_tfdata_datasets):

```
# Prepare the training dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

# Prepare the validation dataset
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(64)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=3, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

You could create those two datasets from `numpy` arrays (`(x_train, y_train)` and `(x_val, y_val)`) using simple slicing as shown there:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]
```

There are also other ways to create `tf.data.Dataset` objects, see [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) documentation and related tutorials/notebooks.